# How to set a class in my own framework to be editable

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am going to create a framework to connections; There are the number of settings related to project such as domain and port, and I want to use this value in my framework;

What is the best solution to do this? (I don't want to put these settings in project -> Build Settings)

Comment: Are these things that can be changed as the program runs or are they to be built in?

Comment: These change only in build time!

Answer (score 1):

I can't say this is a best way, just one option.

In your framework, an initial function should be set ( or a class ). for example:

```
@interface Util
+(void)initialSetting:(NSDictionary*)parmas
@end
```

then put your settings into a plist file. (you can also use system setting to hold these params)

```
example.plist.
```

After App run, then you can read settings from plist file, then feed them in the initial function.Just like this:

```
NSString * filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example.plist" ofType:nil];
NSDictionary * dic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[Util initialSetting:dic]
```

Comment: I don't want use plist or system setting! Actually I am looking for a way to keep a class of framework open to edit or put an interface in my framework and implement it in project!